# TouchDevice not detected

Tags: qt, ubuntu, touchscreen

I'm running ubuntu 15.10 with a hanns.g touchscreen

On ubuntu : touch and gesture work partially prooving that ubuntu know about the touchscreen

With Qt:

```
qDebug() << QTouchDevice::devices().count()
```

is 0

Qt doesn't seems to detect the touchscreen

Why is that ? How can I fix it

EDIT :

The touch is connected via usb

the monitor is a hanns.g ht231

Comment: Provide information about the hardware platform and how the touchscreen is connected to the rest of the system.

Comment: @claudio : I edited with the informations you asked